# How to reproduce this Code Completion bug?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, code-completion

I'm having a bug on Delphi XE2 (Update 4 Hotfix 1), which reproduces many times on the legacy project I work (it evolved from D6 to D7,D2006 and finally XE2), but I didn't know how to trigger it in a smaller project.

The latest time, it triggered on creating an event handler for a "hidden popup" on the app. When I click on the menu option to create the Click handler this happens.

```
pprocedure TMainForm.Blablabla1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

rocedure TMainForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
```

You can see that the IDE inserted the new code INSIDE the declaration of the next method... But it's not all.
Almost all times, on the DPR, code gets mangled too:

```
  AApplication.CreateForm(TDM_DataAcc, DM_DataAcc);
  AApplication.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  pplication.CreateForm(Tfrm_login, frm_login);
  f frm_Login.CanLogin = mrOK then Application.Run
```

(It's almost like that, I don't remember if the 3rd Application.CreateForm get its' 'A' clipped or not, the other I'm sure are doubled and the `IF` gets its' "I" clipped).

Chasing on QualityCentral doesn't help (found nothing). This also happens sometimes on Class Completion(Ctrl-SHift-C).

Someone knows what triggers that bug, so I can create an new application and send it to Embarcadero?

Comment: Did you use the code formatter?

Comment: @SirRufo: No, not in that form (the main form).

Comment: I have seen that happen too. Especially the first example you give. And I know it wasn't because of miscounts in characters in the file as my sources are ANSI only and are always created with CRLF pairs. IDE was D5 or D6, but have seen it in D2009 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behavior like that suggests that the IDE is miscounting characters in the file. There are several "file oddities" that the developers might not have anticipated and that could cause a character index to be miscalculated.

- Check your file for unusual line endings. For example, a line missing a carriage return will appear correctly in the editor, but can cause incorrect line numbers elsewhere in the program.
- Non-breaking spaces are another kind of character that will appear normally, and maybe even parse correctly, but occupies multiple bytes when represented in UTF-8 when the "normal" version of the character (a regular space) only takes up one. You will sometimes acquire such characters if you copy code from a Web browser.
- Incorrect byte-order marks for UTF-8 or UTF-16 source files might also cause problems.

Often, opening your source file in Notepad or a hex editor will help you identify these problems.

Comment: For some strange reason the files have some lines (or the entire file) with Unix linebreaks. ...

Comment: Yes, it suggests that, but I have seen it happen with Ansi only files that all contain CRLF linebreaks...

Comment: @MarjanVenema: when I converted (with Notepad++) the files involved to Windows (CRLF) linebreaks, all started working right again. Btw, do you the fastest way to convert linebreaks of all files of a project (or even an folder) in batch?.... Just to be sure.... ;-)

Comment: @FabricioAraujo: not saying that miscounts are not a factor, just that I have seen the symptoms without that as a cause as well... May be some interaction. Write a simple program that reads all files, scans for single CR or LF and writes back with CRLF pairs. Should be simple enough to write and will save lot of time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: And that is even quicker that writing a small console app... :-))

Comment: @MarjanVenema That program exists. It's called `unix2dos`. This particular wheel was invented a loooooong time ago.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah, but to remember the name is the tricky part!

Comment: @MarjanVenema: **MAYBE**(and that it's a big maybe) that would be an artifact from a recent CVS to SVN conversion of the repository.