# Determine if a process is active

Tags: delphi

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,Tlhelp32, StdCtrls;

  function processExists(exeFileName: string): Boolean; 
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL; 
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle; 
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32); 
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32); 
  Result := False;
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do 
  begin 
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) = 
      UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) = 
      UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
    begin 
      Result := True; 
    end; 
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32); 
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle); 
end; 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if processExists('notepad.exe') then 
    ShowMessage('process is running')
  else 
    ShowMessage('process not running');
end;

enprocedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

That is my exact code im getting errors on  , it is the example from delphi tricks.     now im just trying to fill up my edit so that stackoverflow will let me post my edit, i apparently have mostly code so i need to politely add more detail

Comment: "I keep getting errors" What errors? On what line of the code. Maybe edit your question and paste your exact code into it.

Comment: Did you try calling `EnumProcesses`?

Comment: Call enumProcesses? let me read over it again, and i will also post error

Comment: It looks like you stumbled on the common code-completion issues - when you create a new procedure as an event handler by double-clicking an event in the object inspector, sometimes it injects the new procedure in a slightly off-set location, causing the code to get mixed up. This is why you have one line beginning with `enprocedure` because the `en` part was supposed to be the `end.` Either way, you should have had a `d.` after this.

Comment: @JerryDodge That's the symptom, not the disease. The problem is caused by the source having mixed line-ending characters (some lines finish with LF, others with CRLF and maybe other with only CR) and delphi IDE parses it wrongly. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14243629/10300

Comment: @FabricioAraujo Yes, I never said it was the problem, and that's why I put it as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in your question is failing you because you've managed to copy the content of the function `processExists` into the FormCreate method instead of into the actual function itself.

remove code from `FormCreate` and implement the function `processExists` in the implementation section  :

```
function processExists(exeFileName : string) : Boolean;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  Result := False;
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
    begin
      Result := True;
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);  
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if processExists('notepad.exe') then
    ShowMessage('process is running')
  else
    ShowMessage('process not running');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked great! wow now ive gotta read over this and figure it all out, i didnt think about the implementations section... i need to study more on sections

Comment: @Sheep, Yes, you can do that. Select the code that you have in your Button1Click method and move or copy-paste it to the method(FormCreate) associated with the OnCreate event, then the same code will fire when the form is created. I also suggest you look at David answer, while not on point with the question, he raises some valid points regarding the code.

Comment: @PeterVonča I'm not so sure that my answer is "not on point". I cannot actually see a direct question. The code in the question does not even compile. I just provided a decent implementation of `ProcessExists` that fixes the myriad of problems.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, The question is not about the validity of the code but rather "why does this not compile" or "why does this give me errors". I agree, the code is horrid but it does not result in an error that would be the reason for him asking this question.

Comment: My point is that there is actually no question. Which part of the text above is a question? And also the code posted does not compile because there is no implementation of  processExists and the unit does not end. I did not want to repeat what you said regarding FormCreate since you'd said it fine and your answer was accepted. I wanted to make sure that at least somebody gave an answer with sane code. Although probably nobody will ever get down to my answer.

Comment: I think it's great that the code bothers you , it bothers me, but the validity of the code wasn't the facilitating factor for this question. And there is a question, just because the senteance isn't formed correctly to count as a question, it shouldn't stop you from counting it as such. Some people don't know English that well or it isn't their native language and therefor can make improper questions. Given that you can edit the question, I don't see why you cannot correct it yourself to make it more presentable.

Comment: I honestly cannot see a question in the current version. Please tell me what the question is, and which part of the text contains the question. And for your information we care very much about the quality of questions. Poorly asked questions have little value for the future. We like questions with titles that are questions. We like to see questions marks too!

Comment: When I was talking about editing & correcting the question I meant it as modifying the text of the entire post(SO question) to make it more presentable as a question. The text alone isn't formed as a question, but at the start he does at least state that he is receiving errors with the code in context, and that gives some insight at what he is trying to say. I do hope that he edits the question himself otherwise someone else will have to since it is as you say important that the question be asked correctly for the sake of anyone who might be looking for the same answer in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The code appears to be in the wrong place. We cannot see your implementation of `ProcessExists`, but that's where the code should live.

But I want to concentrate on the code in the question which contains multiple errors. Here's how I would write it:

```
function ProcessExists(const ExeFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  SnapshotHandle: THandle;
  ProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
  Continue: BOOL;
begin
  Result := False;
  SnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  Win32Check(SnapshotHandle<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  try
    ProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(ProcessEntry32);
    Continue := Process32First(SnapshotHandle, ProcessEntry32);
    while Continue do
    begin
      if SameText(ProcessEntry32.szExeFile, ExeFileName) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        exit;
      end;
      Continue := Process32Next(SnapshotHandle, ProcessEntry32);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(SnapshotHandle);
  end;
end;
```

The problems that I have addressed:

1. Don't use global variables here. The variables here can all be, and should be, local variables. Favour local variables over all other variables, and use them wherever possible.
2. Don't cast a `BOOL` to integer and compare against 0. A `BOOL` is a logical and so can be used directly in a logical context.
3. Use `SameText` rather than that `UpperCase` mess.
4. Don't perform the same text comparison twice. Once is enough.
5. Break out of the loop when you find a match.
6. Use try/finally to defend against exceptions leading to resource leak.

Answer (score 1):

The code showed in the linked page is using the [ToolHelp API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Windows.You should give an look on the linked page.

When you use that API, you create an snapshot of the OS current processes' list and use the Process32First and Process32Next to walk over that list to detect that process.

Suggestion: the MadKernel part of [MadCollection](http://www.madshi.net/) (MadExcept and MadCodeHook are the paid parts) does an very nice and useful wrapper around those functions. Those calls made my 50-lines function to send message to the parent app to a 10lines-one.

PS: I've no relation to madshi.net other than using their libs ;-)

Comment: Also, this will run just fine for me.. but it will only get apps inside of delphi, i want it to do it to external applications